# Debian Server System time and time used by processes are different

Tags: debian, ntp, ntpdate

I have a dedicated server running debian 7, the system time shows

"Wed Aug  7 04:28:26 EAT 2013"

I have restarted the server several times but processes like deluge and apache return http headers with time : 
"Wed, 7 Aug 2013 01:28:05 GMT"

Please help, it is causing cookie expiration issues

Comment: Those times look correct. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Many applications use [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) to transport time data even though the system time uses another timezone. This is no need for concern. Just add 3 hours for EAT.

Comment: In fact, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639028/473915) HTTP is required to use GMT for all date/time stamps, with ***no exceptions***.

Comment: @DerfK: I wasn't sure if it was a requirement. Thanks for the info.